# How to remove a character not within an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to remove or manipulate a string within an HTML element but how would I do that if it's outside of an HTML element. I'm trying to remove the (|) character but not really sure how to do it using javascript.

```
<html>

<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    |
    <p>World</p>
    |
    <p>!</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `innerHTML` with text replacement would probably be the easiest thing to wrap your head around, but it's really slow and really bad practise.
There are sure libraries that can do what you want, but I don't like requiring huge libraries for such simple tasks.
So here's a pure JavaScript way:

Text nodes are just like element nodes in terms of adding, removing and changing the contained text.
You can get a hold of the first "|" via `document.body.firstElementChild.nextSibling`, and then you can remove it from its parent or edit its contents like normal:

```
var textNode1 = document.body.firstElementChild.nextSibling;
var textNode2 = textNode1.nextSibling.nextSibling;
// Remove the first text node
textNode1.parentNode.removeChild(textNode1);
// Replace the second by something else
textNode2.textContent = 'Derp';
```

[ [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5L8n6ra/) ]

If you need to, you can also check whether a node is a text node or something else by checking `.nodeType`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.body.childNodes.length; i++)
{
    if(document.body.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) // "3" means text node
    {
        document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Possible values of `.nodeType` and their meanings are listed at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp) or [the DOM Level 1 Specification (pages 25-28)](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/DOM.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) in combination with [`$.fn.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`$.fn.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> The read-only Node.nodeType property returns an unsigned short integer representing the type of the node.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('div').contents().filter(function(){
       return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.textContent.trim()=='|';
     }).remove();
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  |
  <p>World</p>
  |
  <p>!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla-JavaScript, recursive solution that removes all text not within the "normal" nodes. By that, I mean text that is not within the following tags:

```
[ "a", "p", "script", "span", "b", "em", "strong", "i" ]
```

which are generally the one which have only text nodes as children.

```js
// these elements can have text-only nodes
var okayTypes = [ "a", "p", "script", "span", "b", "em", "strong", "i" ]
var removeAllText = function (node) {
    // if the nodeType is 3 (text node) and the nodeName is "#text"
    if (node.nodeName == "#text") {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    } else if (node.childNodes) {
        for (var i = node.childNodes.length; i--;) {
            // if the child element does not allow text-only nodes, recurse on it
            if (okayTypes.indexOf(String(node.childNodes[i].tagName).toLowerCase()) == -1)
                removeAllText(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
removeAllText(document.body);
```

```html
<body>
<p>do not remove 1</p>
remove1
<p>do not remove 2</p>
remove2
<p>do not remove 3</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the [direct descendants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) of the node you're inspecting, `<body>` in this case, and remove each text node you encounter.

```js
var root = document.body;
[].forEach.call(root.childNodes, function(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    root.removeChild(node);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    |
    <p>World</p>
    |
    <p>!</p>
</body>
```